# How to XSLT format long date

Tags: java, xml, xslt, date-format

I have an XML object that is passed to the XSL transformer, 
The date that is passed is in long representation

```
<xsl:variable name="nominationEffectiveDate" select="NomApprovalCase/nominationEffectiveDate"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$nominationEffectiveDate !=''">
      <xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('MMM, dd yyyy'), java:java.util.Date.new(number($nominationEffectiveDate)))" />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>the start of the demand response period<![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I've added a snippet of my XSL the date is coming for example like '1383264000000' and I want it to be something like 'June 1, 2013'. However, running the transofrmation gives the error below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: customernotify, method: template$dot$0 signature: (Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;I)V) Expecting to find double on stack
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.getTransletInstance(TemplatesImpl.java:364)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.newTransformer(TemplatesImpl.java:394)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:649)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.xmlprocessing.GenerateEmailPreview.generate(GenerateEmailPreview.java:30)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.CustomerEmailGenerator.generateHtml(CustomerEmailGenerator.java:65)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.EmailPreviewerPlugin$EmailPreviewProcessor.process(EmailPreviewerPlugin.java:169)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.EmailPreviewerPlugin$EmailPreviewProcessor.process(EmailPreviewerPlugin.java:1)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.DqCheckProcessor.process(DqCheckProcessor.java:93)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.DqCheckProcessor.process(DqCheckProcessor.java:1)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.Salesforce.call(Salesforce.java:87)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.EmailPreviewerPlugin$MyCallable.call(EmailPreviewerPlugin.java:102)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.nomapproval.EmailPreviewerPlugin$MyCallable.call(EmailPreviewerPlugin.java:1)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.pipeline.push.framework.AbstractPlugin.call(AbstractPlugin.java:44)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.pipeline.push.framework.AbstractPlugin.call(AbstractPlugin.java:1)
>       at com.enernoc.pe.applications.scheduledbatch.Main.main(Main.java:196)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<xsl:when test="number($nominationEffectiveDate)">
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:when>
```

A test against `''` does not protect you from `NaN` values.

Comment: I was getting the error in the  <xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('MMM, dd yyyy'), java:java.util.Date.new(number($nominationEffectiveDate)))" /> line, simply the new from long value doesn't work from the XSL and I have to externalize it to get it working

Comment: @KhaledAbdel-Salam: can you please provide working copy of code. i am also getting same issue.